# How to uninstall VMware player in linux

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation

When I start the installer for VMware workstation it says that I have to first uninstall VMware player. But how can I do that? It's not like I installed it with apt-get. I downloaded the .bundle file from the website, so I don't know of any automatic way to uninstall it so that the workstation installer will stop complaining.

Answer (score 7):

Run this as root:

```
vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Answer (score 2):

In case, no PRODUCT is mentioned as **vmware-workstation**, check for **vmware-player**
Run `vmware-installer -u vmware-player` as root.

It worked in my case.